# How can I remove the Select All option from drop down in the Magento 2 admin product grid?

Tags: magento2, product, uicomponent

I want to remove the Select All option from the drop down in the Magento 2 admin product grid.
[image]

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

For this, you have to create your own js which will extend the UI component multi-select js "module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/multiselect.js".

```
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/multiselect</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
```

Now create a js in app/code/Vendor/Module/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/mulitselect.js

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'mage/translate',
  'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/multiselect',
], function (_, $t, Column) {
   'use strict';

   return Column.extend({
      initialize: function () {
          this._super();
          //selectAll and deselectAll are first two options in ui multiselect js
          this.actions.splice(0,2);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: hi @Afreen, how can we remove Select all on this page option here

Comment: just follow the above answer guidelines. you will be to remove "Select All".

Comment: sorry @Afreen, my typing mistake,  I need to remove Select on this page option

Comment: if you dont want the select feature then you should remove the whole tag of "selectionsColumn".

Comment: yes @Afreen, possible to update me, how to remove that

Comment: remove this whole code from your ui component xml  
  
`<selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/multiselect</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>`

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: hi @Afreen,after removing those lines i am getting this error.
Undefined index: attributes in magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php on line 176

Comment: @jafarpinjar can you provide me the code. removing selectionColumns does nto effect any other element.

Answer (score -1):

Magento 2 used UI Component to render products grid at admin, you can use CSS to hide from dropdown.

```
.catalog-product-index .data-grid-multicheck-cell .action-menu > li:first-child { display: none; }
.catalog-product-index .data-grid-multicheck-cell label { pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: using css to hide something is not as per magento standard